# How can I access the array saved in the for loop? (objective c)

Tags: ios, objective-c, parse-platform

```
-(void) queryRestuarantsName {

NSMutableArray* restaurantNameArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"Menus"];
[query selectKeys: @[@"Resturant", @"Description", @"Name"]];
query.limit = 1000000;

[query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {


        for (PFObject *object in objects) {

            NSString* restaurant = [object objectForKey: @"Resturant"];
            [restaurantNameArray addObject:restaurant];

        }    
}];

}
```

Currently, outside of the for loop, `restaurantNameArray` is said to be empty. However, in the for loop, it has objects. How can I access the objects outside of the loop?

Comment: Where are your trying access `restaurantNameArray` in your code? I don't see it listed in the question. Are you sure you're not trying to access it before your `findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:` block has run?

Comment: You should access it inside the completion block!

Answer (score 1):

It is asynchronous code. Any access to restaurantNameArray before receiving results by findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock will return empty results.

So any processing of data in array should happen only after findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock got results. Likely you expected that following code will work:

```
[self queryRestuarantsName];
[self.tableView reloadData];
```

but it will not as data will not be loaded by this moment. Instead of this reload you data as soon as you received response.

Answer (score 0):

As already said you are using asynchronous task. Think of it as program will just pass it by this block and it will return to it later when it's ready. In your case you could use [blocks](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/WorkingwithBlocks/WorkingwithBlocks.html) to return restourant names and then reload data:

```
-(void)reloadAfterQuery
{
    [self queryRestuarantsName:^(NSArray *restorantNames) {

        //store names, reload table,collection view etc

    }];
}

-(void) queryRestuarantsName:(void(^)(NSArray* restorantNames))callback
{
    NSMutableArray* restaurantNameArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"Menus"];
    [query selectKeys: @[@"Resturant", @"Description", @"Name"]];
    query.limit = 1000000;

    [query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {


        for (PFObject *object in objects) {

            NSString* restaurant = [object objectForKey: @"Resturant"];
            [restaurantNameArray addObject:restaurant];

        }

        callback(restaurantNameArray);

    }];

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Once you fill array inside block , simply use it inside block or  just use it by calling method(code) which uses that array .

Like if you are using array as datasource , then Reload Table inside block.